# PHP cookies / actions

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to store a cookie on my login.php page so i can keep users logged in. but they aren't showing up...  this is just a test one but eventually i would like to store the username/password so the user can stay logged in when they close out of the browser.

### Login.php

```
<?php

if ($_GET["action"]=="loginAction"){

    setcookie('cookie','yum',time()+3600, '/');

}

?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/SITE/index.php?action=loginAction" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username"  placeholder="Name">
    <input type="password" value="" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button id="hideme" name="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The browser rejects the stinky name you are giving to your cookie. That's all!

Comment: I meant to change that sorry!

Comment: Where are you not seeing the cookie? AFAIK the cookie doesn't actually exist until you actually submit, then it comes back with the response.

Comment: I cant find the cookie anywhere. I've tried just setting the cookie without the "if ()" and reloading the page.. but nothing

Answer (score 1):

Be aware the the user can manipulate a cookie. You should take a look at sessions (http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). You could consider them as cookies on the serverside. But then be aware of session hijacking... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)

Answer (score 0):

`setcookie` needs to be output before any other output to the browser. It looks like you are trying to use `setcookie` inside of a script.

You can check if the cookie is set, if output the result of `setcookie`.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman

Are you talking something like this

```
<?php
    setcookie('cookie','yum',time()+3600);
    echo $_COOKIE["cookie"];
?>
```

my url : site.com/site/index.php?action=loginAction